# Javascript count two variables goes wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I am busy with making a kind of invoice system, where the user can make invoices very easily. Now I am at the point where I have to count up, per product, three different variables/items, but instead of counting them up, my javascript code puts it like text (with the + operator).

Example:

selectmenu 1  = option 0 (where VAT = 8.50 euro's)
selectmenu 2  = option 1 (where VAT = 12.76 euro's)

Now the output has to be (8.50+12.76)= 21.26

The output in my situation is = 8.5012.76

**My (partial) javascript code:**

```
$("select#product").on("change", function (e) {
    var $row = $(e.target).closest('.productitem');
    var selVal = $row.find('#product').val();

    var totalvat;
    var currentVat = $('#totalvat').val();
    var NLhoog = 1.21;

    var price0EXC = 40.49;
    var price0INC = (price0EXC * NLhoog).toFixed(2);
    var price0VAT = (price0INC - price0EXC).toFixed(2);
    var price1EXC = 60.74;
    var price1INC = (price1EXC * NLhoog).toFixed(2);
    var price1VAT = (price1INC - price1EXC).toFixed(2);

    if (selVal === "0") {
        $row.find("input#vat").val(price0VAT);
        $row.find("input#priceEXC").val(price0EXC);
        $row.find("input#priceINC").val(price0INC);

        totalvat = (currentVat + price0VAT);
        $('input#totalvat').val(totalvat);

    } else if (selVal === "1") {
        $row.find("input#vat").val(price1VAT);
        $row.find("input#priceEXC").val(price1EXC);
        $row.find("input#priceINC").val(price1INC);

        totalvat = currentVat+price1VAT;
        $('input#totalvat').val(totalvat);

    }
});
```

I have let the unimportant part of the code away.
If you know what I am doing wrong, please let me know :)

Comment: Parse the `currentVat` and `priceVAT` values as floats using `parseFloat` before summing them up.

Comment: Because `currentvat` is a string. You need to `parseFloat` beforehand.

Comment: It looks like your HTML has duplicate IDs. Does it?

Comment: `+` on strings will concatenate them. You must first convert the strings to numbers, then `+` will add them numerically.

Comment: + does summation on numbers and concatenation on strings. `8.50 + 12.76 = 21.26` but `"8.50" + "12.76" = "8.5012.76"` Be mindfull that calling toFixed() on a number will also return a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this may help?

```
var currentVat = parseFloat($('#totalvat').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var currentVat = $('#totalvat').val();` to get the value from an input I assume? This is a string which will need to be parsed at some to a relevant datatype. When `+` is used with a string the compiler performs concatenation.

Try something like:

```
var currentVat = parseFloat($('#totalvat').val());
```

Or do it later on with:

```
parseFloat(currentVat);
```

As you're using numbers as currency I'd consider adding the suffix `.ToFixed(2)` at the end, and maybe some other formatting